# how to use gsub for "\\n\\n" correctly?

Tags: r, regex, text, gsub

Using `gsub()`, I want to replace "\n\n" to "" in this text:

```
mystring<-"People Storm Seonul Airport as Citizens Leave\\n\\nCHOI JEONGHO\\n\\nSEOUL, South Korea, Jan. 31"
```

But, when I ran `gsub("[\r\\n]", " ", mystring)`, it deletes all n in the text.

The output was:

```
"People Storm Seo ul  Airport as Citize s Leave    CHOI JEO GHO    SEOUL, South Korea, Ja . 31"
```

Could you teach me why it is so and how to delete only "\n\n"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don’t want to use brackets because you’re trying to match a sequence of characters — brackets will match any of the characters individually, which is how you end up with no `n`s.
2. To match a literal `\\n`, you need to escape both backslashes, giving you `\\\\n`.

```
gsub("(\r)|(\\\\n)", " ", mystring)

# "People Storm Seonul Airport as Citizens Leave  CHOI JEONGHO  SEOUL, South Korea, Jan. 31"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option with the `stringr` package. In R, you need to escape backslashes using `\\`, so you'll need to use `\\\\n` as your argument:

```r
stringr::str_remove_all(mystring, "\\\\n")

"People Storm Seonul Airport as Citizens LeaveCHOI JEONGHOSEOUL, South Korea, Jan. 31"
```